# Can't uninstall VMware player 5.0 from computer with Hyper-V

Tags: vmware-player, hyper-v

I had installed VMware player on my computer. Later I installed Hyper-V on my computer.

Now, when I try to uninstall VMware player, I get this message:

[image: HyperV Error]

Can anybody provide a way to remove VMware without removing Hyper-V?
My OS is Windows 8 Enterprise.

Comment: This made my day. Stupid pre-install checks.... If the installation is done via MSI. You can use orca to remove all the checks.

Comment: Do you still have this problem if 5.0.1 is used?  There was an update on November 6th.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Modify the file

```
C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Player\Uninstaller\bootstrap.lua
```

or

```
C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation\Uninstaller\bootstrap.lua
```

using a text editor and comment out line

```
CheckForMSHyperV()
```

with two dashes, so it will become

```
--CheckForMSHyperV()
```

Then save the file and rerun the uninstall and it will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this simply turn off Hyper-V, and then restart, uninstall VMware, re-add Hyper-V.

If you feel like going hunting in the registry there is probably another way, but this way is easier and safer.

Comment: Yeah, very "easy" and much "safer"! - only takes two reboots and potential virtual switch snafus!